# How can I free space from a massive 39.5GB /var/log/ folder?

Tags: disk-usage, logging

I just got a message from the default disk analyses software (Baobab)
that I only have 1GB left on the hard drive. After some search, I found that the `/var/log/` folder is the cause of this.

Some file/sizes in `/var/log/`:

- kern.log     = 12.6 GB
- ufw.log      = 12.5 GB
- kern.log.1   =  6.1 GB
- ufw.log.1    =  6.0 GB

Et cetera et cetera. `/var/log` is huge.

Can I delete those files or the entire `/var/log` folder? Or is that a BIG NO NO in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You must not remove the entire folder **but** you can remove "Old-Packed" log files without harming your system.

For a typical home user, it's safe to remove any log file that is compressed and has a **.gz** extension (as you can see in the picture).

These compressed log files are old logs that are gzipped to reduce storage space, and as an average user, you don't need them.

[image: Select .gz extention]

Comment: find /var/log -type f -name "*.gz" -exec rm -f {} \;

Comment: @diyism i tried your code, but not much help. my log dir still use 6GB space @_@

Comment: `find /var/log -type f -name "*.gz" -delete`, 
I removed the compressed files and I only freed around 1 GB of space. Isn't 50 GB enough for the `/` dir and the rest of my disk for `/home` !

Comment: My mother's PC had a **kern.log** file 21 GB in size. A big *kern.log* indicates problem in the Linux kernel itself or in something it's experiencing issues in dealing with. In both cases, it's recommended to go to the Linux shell terminal and run `cat /var/log/kern.log` or `nano /var/log/kern.log` (at the GUI, run something like e.g. `gedit /var/log/kern.log` or `mousepad /var/log/kern.log`) and check what may be the problem. Once you figure out what's wrong you can then run `sudo rm /var/log/kern.log ; sudo telinit 6` in order to delete such (big) file and restart the operating system.

Comment: In my case, this will remove only 15.7 MB of 41 files. The real problems here are `messages` (7.7 GB), `user.log` (7.7 GB), `syslog` (4.1 GB) and `syslog.1` (3.5 GB). Those four files sum 23 GB. Any way to remove them, or at least reduce their size?

Comment: @YuriSucupira I don't think it's a smart idea to cat (`cat /var/log/kern.log`) the whole log file

Comment: @Ismail I know that running `cat` on a big file is gonna take a lot of time, but if such file is the only source of information you got about the issue that's affecting your OS then it might be the only way. Anyway, if one alternatively prefers to delete the log file except its last **N** lines, one can run a command like this: `tail -N /var/log/kern.log |sudo tee /var/log/kernel.log`. If e.g. one wants to keep only the last 1000 lines, just run `tail -1000 /var/log/kern.log |sudo tee /var/log/kernel.log`and the kernel log will be downsized to a file having only its last 1000 lines.

Comment: @Ismail Another good use for `tail` is to preserve the `kern.log` file while the user doesn't figure out what's wrong with the system. Such user may use `grep` into `kernel.log`'s last **N** lines with a command such as `tail -N /var/log/kern.log |grep -i word` where **N** is the last N lines of the `kern.log` file and `word` is a word the user suspects (s)he may find into such lines, about the issue affecting the system. Last but not least, `tail -N /var/log/kern.log |sudo tee /var/log/analysis.log` will create `analysis.log`, which has only the last **N** lines of `kernel.log`.

Comment: Despite these big log files (which can just be deleted or alternatively "downsized" with `tail` as I explained above), a good "everyday use" app for cleaning the system is Bleachbit (check https://www.bleachbit.org), which you can install with `sudo apt-get install bleachbit -y`.

Comment: @YuriSucupira `cat` isn't the only simplified tool, there are multiple ways of doing this. It was just a simple suggestion that you shouldn't recommend people to use cat, use `less` instead. Yes for a big file it's smarter to use `tail` than `cat` since cat outputs everything and only the last x lines(dependent on your terminal settings) will be visible.

Comment: @Ismail I use `less` (and `more`) in some contexts, but because the OP / question refers to a massively big log file I would never use `less`: in such context, using `less` would cause it to take _forever_ to find anything relevant inside such massive log file. Anyway, you're right about `tail`, it is smarter than using `cat`. **^..^**

Comment: As @Rodrigo mentioned above, this only removes the smallest files. This answer from richvdh below actually solves it. https://askubuntu.com/a/100014/315699

Answer (score 40):

I wouldn't delete the entire /var/log folder - that will break things.

You could just destroy the logs as @jrg suggests - but unless the things writing to the log files (mostly syslogd) are restarted that won't actually regain you any disk space, as the files will continue to exist in a deleted state until the filehandles are closed.

Better would be to find out why the logs aren't being rotated (and later deleted). [logrotate](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man8/logrotate.8.html) is supposed to do this for you, and I suspect it's not being run each night as it should.

First thing I would do would be:

```
sudo /etc/cron.daily/logrotate
```

This *should* rotate the log files (so kern.log becomes kern.log.1); and you can then delete kern.log.1 etc to free up the disk space.

If everything is good so far, the next question is why this isn't happening automatically. If you turn your computer off at night, make sure you have [anacron](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/anacron) installed.

Comment: I executed `sudo /etc/cron.daily/logrotate` and the files did not change

Comment: I used `logrotate -vf /etc/logrotate.conf` to manually rotates the logs. Source: https://www.linuxnix.com/how-to-rotate-logs-manually-in-linux/

Answer (score 39):

DISCLAIMER: I am not an expert on this, use at own risk!

After finding that my `/var/log/journal` folder was taking several GB, I followed:

https://ma.ttias.be/clear-systemd-journal/

```bsh
journalctl --vacuum-time=10d
```

which cleared 90%+ of it

Comment: Works like a charm in Ubuntu 18, 20 and 22.

Answer (score 19):

You should look at the logs and see what is getting written to them. My guess is ufw/iptables (you are logging all network traffic).

ufw - when you log all packets, you will get large logs. If you are not going to review the logs, turn logging off. If you wish to monitor your network, use snort. Snort will filter through the thousands of packets you receive and alert you to potentially problematic traffic.

My guess it that ufw is the culprit and you are getting a large log in kern.log because you are logging packets there as well.

Sometimes there is a kernel or hardware problem that fills the logs. In that event it is best to fix the problem or file a bug, you will need to review the logs to do that.

If you can not fix the problem, you can configure syslog to as to not fill your logs.

See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/syslog.conf.5.html

If you provide more details on the problem we can help debug it better.

Comment: That's a very good point. It's worth finding out what's clogging up the logs rather than just deleting them. +1.

Answer (score 8):

Deleting `/var/log` is probably a bad idea, but deleting the individual logfiles should be OK.

On my laptop, with a smallish SSD disk, I set up `/var/log` (and `/tmp` and `/var/tmp`) as `tmpfs` mount points, by adding the following lines to `/etc/fstab`:

```
temp        /tmp        tmpfs   rw,mode=1777    0   0
vartmp      /var/tmp    tmpfs   rw,mode=1777    0   0
varlog      /var/log    tmpfs   rw,mode=1777    0   0
```

This means that *nothing* in those directories survives a reboot.  As far as I can tell, this setup works just fine.  Of course, I lose the ability to look at old logs to diagnose any problems that might occur, but I consider that a fair tradeoff for the reduced disk usage.

The only problem I've had is that some programs (most notably APT) want to write their logs into subdirectories of `/var/log` and aren't smart enough to create those directories if they don't exist.  Adding the line `mkdir /var/log/apt` into `/etc/rc.local` fixed that particular problem for me; depending on just what software you have installed, you may need to create some other directories too.

(Another possibility would be to create a simple `tar` archive containing just the directories, and to untar it into `/var/log` at startup to create all the needed directories and set their permissions all at once.)

Comment: ufw was the probleem apparently i set the logging to FULL so it logde everything. thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 8):

I had and issue with enormous log files (like 100G each) with some useless messages from gnome 'cannot find video buffer' or something. Doing:

`sudo rm -rf /var/log/user.log
sudo rm -rf /var/log/syslog
sudo rm -rf /var/log/messages`

did not solve the problem, but doing 
`systemctl restart syslog.service`
right after freed space used by those files.

Comment: Would it be rsyslog now?
https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/rsyslog-systemd-journald-linux-logs

Comment: @Pysis seems like. On Debian still `syslog` works though but returns `rsyslog`.

Answer (score 3):

I had a several GBytes `/var/log` folder that I made shrink to less than 250MBytes using both `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` and `logrotate`:

config for journald: (cf `man journald.conf`)

```
SystemMaxUse=250M
SystemMaxFileSize=50M
```

config for `/etc/logrotate.conf`:

```
compress

/var/log/journal {
    daily
    dateext
    delaycompress
    copytruncate
    notifempty
    missingok
    rotate 3
    size 500k
    sharedscripts
}
```

also look into files in `/etc/logrotate.d/*`

Comment: This isn't a solution. Even if you make this change to logrotete configuration, logfiles can grow to multi GB between logrotete is run - typecally once a day. Look in the largest of the active logfile (with tail -f filename.log) to determine what are the real problem, and then fix this promlem.

Comment: @SorenA `$ du -sh /var/log` now evaluates to 233M , whereas it was almost 5GB before. Maybe there remains issues for you, but it is a clearly a solution for the question about a "massive /var/log".

Comment: It's not professional to remove the symptom instead of the cause.You will end up with log-files with all kinds of "noise", or so short-lived, so that the day your sever have a real problem, the log-files don't contain the needed histiric data, or you can't find them among all the garbage.

Comment: @SorenA thanks for the remark. I peeked more closely at logs , and noticed a recurring error message which seems recurring often enough to be responsible for GBytes over months. Not crucial, but gotta fix this issue.

Comment: don't limit it too much, or you will not be able to find noise making apps, e.g.: `sudo sed s/#SystemMaxUse=$/SystemMaxUse=500M/g /etc/systemd/journald.conf -i`