# Server logs are filling my hard disk, how do I fix this?

Tags: 12.04, server, disk-usage

I have Ubuntu 12.04 which serves my web application (20 MB) on apache httpd. Here is my partitions table:

```
$ sudo parted -l

Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Partition Table: gpt

Number|Start|End|Size|File System|Name|Flag
1|17.4K|20.0MB|20.0MB|fat16| |boot
2|20.0MB|489GB|489GB|ext4
3|489GB|500GB|10.6GB|linux-swap(v1)
```

A few days ago I upgrade it to 12.10. Then copied one folder (30 GB) to www folder. Suddenly the server hang and I got a **Low Graphics Mode message**. I removed the huge folder and restarted the computer but still got the same message and `No Space Left on Device`

```
$ sudo du -h /var --max-depth=1

4.0K  /var/tmp
235M  /var/www
444G  /var/log
```

So, the /var/log is huge.

I tried:

```
$ sudo apt-get autoclean;sudo apt-get autoremove
**Error! No space left on device**
```

I did delete the archives logs but nothing changes
the largest file is `/var/log/cups` and when I list its files, I got:

```
-rw-r----- 1 root adm 758 DEC 30 07:37 access_log.1.gz
..
**-rw-r----- 1 root adm 444G JAN 5 08:09 error_log**
-rw-r----- 1 root adm 245 DEC 29 13:17 error_log.1.gz
```

I tried:

```
$ sudo service cups stop
sudo: unable to write to /var/lib/sudo/username/tty2: No space left on device
```

When I unplugged the computer then replugged it. it works fine and problem gone. The `/var` size is completely normal.

I'm afraid of facing it again. I think my main problem is because of the partitions. The `/home` and `/root` are together and not separated. Do I have to create a new partition for `/home`? Anyone has another idea how to avoid the disk from filling up again?

Comment: Your disk *is full*. What makes you believe it isn't? Boot into recovery and remove some files. After you get the system up, use `du` or `ncdu` to see what files are eating all your space. For servers I highly recommend monitoring applications for disk space to prevent system outage.

Comment: Free monitoring software, xymon: http://xymon.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Is that a remote server? If you can still access it please post the results of `df -h` and `du -s /*` so that we can assist with finding the "lost" space.

Comment: "Is there anyway to save me and my server without a format ?"  Who gave you the idea that a full disc requires a format of a disc?

Comment: Updated my Post

Comment: This should now be closed as 'Too localized' since the problem disappeared and any answers can't be tested. Your follow-up question in the new edit is a [duplicate of this one](http://askubuntu.com/q/247/12864). Good luck & post again if you have any new problems.

Comment: @TomBrossman The answer is quite good, and is applicable to others. This question is effectively resolved, and there is no need to close it as *too localized*. Furthermore, even if this had no answers, we would still wait *more than 5 days* to close it as abandoned! The vast majority of questions that we close as *too localized* because they're abandoned have no useful answers and are months or years old.

Comment: @EliahKagan Fair enough. It's only got two close-votes now, and I see from the most recent edit that the problem has recurred. It might even be good to merge with [this closely related question](http://askubuntu.com/q/100004/12864), which has some great information.

Answer (score 8):

As you noticed yourself, your log folder is huge. You probably want to delete some old logs. Old logs are being archived periodically. If you look into your log folder by

```
cd /var/log
ls -lh
```

you will see a lot of files ending in `.gz`. Those files are the archives logs. They have a number before that indicating how old the archive is. `.1.gz` is the newest. If you are sure you don't need the old logs any more, delete them:

```
sudo rm *.gz
```

Before you do so you might want to check why your logs are that huge. Take a look which log files and corresponding archives are huge. If you find some look into them. What are the log entries? Are some of them very frequent? What process/program/event is responsible? Can you safely lower the log level for that?

**EDIT**

Look into the `error_log`. You should use `tail` for showing the last few lines and hope that it can process such a huge file. You could also delete that file to free up the space but we should find out why it is that big.

Comment: Additionally it would be a good idea to check if logrotate is properly configured (see `/etc/logrotate.conf` and files in `etc/logrotate.d`)

Comment: Updated my answer ;-)