# Log files (CUPS) grow so fast!

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, log

the past few days I faced a strange issue with my computer. I discussed it here:
[Server logs are filling my hard disk, how do I fix this?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/234989/server-logs-are-filling-my-hard-disk-how-do-i-fix-this)

Shortly, log files (in cups folder) grow so fast! I did solve the problem but I'm afraid of facing it again. I need to know what cause it so that I can avoid it.

I'm not sure but does the fact that I don't separate the root and /home relevant ?

```
sudo parted -l


Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number|Start|End|Size|File System|Name|Flag
1|17.4K|20.0MB|20.0MB|fat16| |boot
2|20.0MB|489GB|489GB|ext4
3|489GB|500GB|10.6GB|linux-swap(v1)
```

**UPDATE**

the problem is back :(

the /var/log/sups is full again (444GB)
I didn't do anything !

```
 ls -l /var/log/cups/

total 464543116
-rw-r----- 1 root adm 0 DEC 30 07:47 access_log
-rw-r----- 1 root adm 587 DEC 30 07:37 access_log.1.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root adm 259 DEC 29 07:59 access_log.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root adm 258 DEC 28 07:41 access_log.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root adm 255 DEC 27 07:23 access_log.4.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root adm 252 DEC 26 07:04 access_log.5.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root adm 230 DEC 25 07:44 access_log.6.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root adm 161 DEC 24 12:18 access_log.7.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root adm 475691855862 Jan 7 07:50 error_log
-rw-r----- 1 root adm 245 DEC 29 14:34 error_log.1.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root adm 0 Feb 29 29 2012 page_log




cat /etc/logrotate.d/cups

    /var/log/cups/*log {
    daily
    missingok
    rotate 7
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
             if [ -e /var/run/cups/cupsd.pid ]; then
                      invoke-rc.d --quiet cups force-reload > /dev/null
                      sleep 10
             fi
    endscript
    compress
    notifempty
    create 640 root lpadmin
    }
```

When I stop cups and remove the file by:

```
sudo service cups stop
sudo rm /var/log/cups/error_log
sudo service cups start
```

the problem gone but I'm afraid it will be back again

Comment: Please show us (within your question) the output of `ls -l /var/log/cups/` and the content of `/etc/logrotate.d/cups`. Then send the biggest file from `/var/log/cups/` to [paste.ubuntu.com](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and show us the url you get from that. The not separate parts of the file system are not relevant here.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like it's the error log that's filling up, not the access log.

1. Check the error log level ("LogLevel") in the config file located at `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf`.
   It should normally be "LogLevel warn" or "LogLevel error". If it's set to "debug" you will get a ton of messages you don't need.
2. Check the error log (`/var/log/cups/error_log`) for errors.
   Given the size, I would do `tail -500 /var/log/cups/error_log > cups_errors`, and then look at `cups_errors`; this file will only have the last 500 lines of the full error.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to edit the *AccessLogLevel* of CUPS.

There are four modes:

- *config* Log when printers and classes are added, deleted, or modified and when configuration files are accessed or updated.
- *actions* Log when print jobs are submitted, held, released, modified, or canceled, and any of the conditions for config.
- *all* Log all requests.

The cupsd.conf is per default located at **/etc/cups/cupsd.conf**.

> I'm not sure but does the fact that I don't separate the root and /home relevant?

Probably not.

Answer (score 1):

First get access to a shell (tty, terminal).

If you can't log in, try [booting into recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode), or log in to a tty session (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>)

While in the shell, run:

```
sudo rm /var/log/error_log*
```

This would free up space. And would allow the system to function normally.

As the problem is with `cups`, I'd recommend that you remove or upgrade it.

```
sudo systemctl stop cups.service
sudo apt purge cups
sudo apt update
sudo apt install cups
```