# Low disk space (free space was > 500 GB yesterday)

Tags: partitioning, disk-usage

Following is the output of `df -h` on my system.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             63G     0   63G   0% /dev
tmpfs            13G   18M   13G   1% /run
/dev/sdc4       822G  801G     0 100% /
tmpfs            63G   64M   63G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            63G     0   63G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme1n1p2   96M   75M   22M  79% /boot/efi
cgmfs           100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs            13G   88K   13G   1% /run/user/1000
```

Using `du -xsch /home`, I get the following:

```
60G /home
60G total
```

Using `free -m`, I get the following:

```
total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         128831        8648       16405         147      103777      118367
Swap:        130986          18      130968
```

I only recently moved to using Linux, so I am not aware yet of how the disk partitioning is used. It also seems weird that my system had more than 500 GB yesterday, but just today it's started to show `Free space: 0 bytes` at the bottom of every folder I open. This space error is causing things to hangup.

**EDIT:** I have deleted some files in excess of 40 GB, but it still shows `Free space: 0 bytes` at the bottom of each folder, and does not allow me to copy any files. I am stunned that it was showing ~550 GB yesterday as the free space and suddenly all of it vanished, although there was nothing I did to occupy that space.

Comment: What about  `/tmp` ?

Comment: Just `$ /tmp` gives `bash: /tmp: Is a directory`

Comment: Please don't use tags that make your question offtopic ;) See the "question you should avoid" here: https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic And do not forget to clear the trash. And `free -m` is about memory,  not diskspace.

Comment: @Rinzwind: Sorry about that. Clearing trash was the first thing I did, because it was recommended in the error I received about the disk space.

Comment: I of course meant the disk usage of /tmp ... `du -sh /tmp` ... @Rinzwind  Trash is part of /home which has only 60G.

Comment: @RoVo sure but the "Free space: 0 bytes at the bottom of every folder I open." is not going to be about /tmp/ I would assume. The issue will be with /home/ ... 60Gb in there. That must be a video I'd bet.

Comment: @RoVo: I get the following: `$ du -sh /tmp
du: cannot read directory '/tmp/systemd-private-1916acb2a3bd41e1b7d45cff70cf4d91-rtkit-daemon.service-4flEKu': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/tmp/systemd-private-1916acb2a3bd41e1b7d45cff70cf4d91-colord.service-H2ci85': Permission denied
2.1M /tmp`

Comment: Add "sudo" before the command @user11

Comment: okay, but then it's not about `/tmp`. sorry.

Comment: @Rinzwind: `$ sudo du -sh /tmp
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set`

Comment: If 801G is used with 60G in /home, and the system takes approximately 15G, what the hell is the other 725G ?? ...  run a  `du -sh /*` to find out. It will take a while.

Comment: @RoVo: After running your suggested command, most of the lines show 'Permission denied', but the last two lines read `758G      /var 0       /vmlinuz`. I have been trying to reboot, but it's not letting me. Currently, running the terminal through `Alt+F2`.

Comment: so it sounds like there's something gigantic in /var - I posted this as an answer, but try something like `find /var -size +1G -type f -exec du -Sh {} + | sort -rh | head -n 5` to try to find out what is so big in /var

Comment: @drkokandy: Yes, I tried your suggestion and I posted a comment about the two files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Root drive is running out of disk space. How can I free up space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57994/root-drive-is-running-out-of-disk-space-how-can-i-free-up-space)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's entirely possible that some file is bloating and eating up your space. I am remembering an old X-org bug where text files would use all your available disk space for logging errors or whatever until you disabled it.

Try running this command in the terminal:

```
find / -size +1G -type f -exec du -Sh {} + | sort -rh | head -n 5
```

You'll probably get a lot of "permission denied" errors, but that should be fine. If a file is ballooning out of control, I would suspect the file will be somewhere in space where you do have permission. That command will return the size and location of the 5 largest files on your system.

If that command does not work due to your lack of space (I think it will), you may have better success doing something like:

```
find / -size +1G | grep -v find | less
```

Which should find any file on your computer that is larger than 1 gigabyte in size, filter out any errors, and present the results for your review. You can then investigate any unfamiliar files.

If there is a file growing uncontrollably, you should then be able to delete it or conduct additional research on what it is - it may be a bug or a log you can disable.

Comment: You could add `-size +1G` for the first command too... should be faster I think.

Comment: good point, if we're looking for like 600+ GB of something, I'll add it

Comment: @drkokandy: On running your 1st command, I see 631G in `/var/log/cups/error_log.1`, and 110G in `/var/log/cups/error_log`. These two files are there besides the other software files that I am aware of and don't suspect any wrong.

Comment: I am suspecting the log files contain warnings about permission to some directory. I remember changing permission to `env/` and its subdirectories yesterday because I wanted to change a file name of a binary in that folder. Could it be because of that as this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/836154/space-on-disk-running-low-error-logging-var-log-cups-error-log) suggests?

Comment: So cups is spewing huge error logs. These logs are not necessary and can be deleted, which will free your space. Check the Log Level that cups is set to in `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf` [via this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/420597/103537) - if it's not "warn" or "error" that's why it's spewing so much. If it is set to one of those, you can try to delete those log files (you may need to force it with like `rm -f /var/log/cups/error_l*` - make sure to enter this command carefully) and then reboot or restart cups.

Comment: @user11 that could be it, especially if that was a recent change just before the problem started - try changing the permissions back

Comment: Maybe first analyze what logs say, then delete them. ;)

Comment: I read first 20 lines of the log and it keeps repeating `File \"/usr/lib/cups/notifier ... has insecure permissions ... went away, retrying!`

Comment: There you go. Remove the logs and change back the permissions. Best would be to file a bug report to cups...

Comment: @RoVo: What is the recommended way to change back the permissions?

Comment: i had this once, were something was wrong with the logging, and i found .log files exceeding 100gb. i had to delete them with sudo also. never happened afterwards though