# Ubuntu Server /var/log crazy disk usage

Tags: apache2

I had small system in my VPS, which only had 10GB disk usage. Now as I check `/var/log` directory used 6GB to only write log!!! which it sound very crazy to me.

[image: Crazy Screenshot]

I have tried cleanup the log following [this suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100004/how-can-i-free-space-from-a-massive-39-5gb-var-log-folder), but still not much help. Is there any reason why the log take so much disk usage? How to fix it? I don't want to have log file that big.

Comment: Do you have log-rotate installed?

Comment: `/var/log` is a folder, not one log file.  Inside that folder, there are many log files.  You need to go into that folder and specifically find the log files that're eating up the space, and remove them or trim them, and delete old logfiles that logrotate left behind.

Comment: @Braiam Nope, never heard of it @_@

Comment: @ThomasW. So basically it safe to just delete all the log file?

Comment: @GusDeCooL no, you should never just delete all the log files.  There's probably certain log files you can safely remove, but I don't know what they are offhand.

Comment: I would add the `ls -l /var/log/` output to know what files are clogging the stuff.

Comment: read the large log files and see what is filling them. 6gb is huge, fix the underlying problem

Comment: @Braiam The once make much space is apache2. it seems there is some error in my apps and it have much visitor. so the logs write each visit.

Comment: So, check the logs, fix the error and install logrotate ;)

Comment: @Braiam i have deleted the logs for temporary fix. It's bloated because i put log for every warn in apache. how stupid I'am @_@

Comment: Yeah, but you should definitely check those errors!

Comment: @Braiam Yes yes, i understand i need to fix that error so it would not happen again @_@

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install **logrotate** to manage your log files:

[How to manage log files](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-manage-log-files-with-logrotate-on-ubuntu-12-10)