# Linux keeps on Logging and freezing after entering password

Tags: 18.04, 19.04

My Laptop can be found [here](https://support.hp.com/in-en/document/c05080824).
For the past 2-3 Weeks I am trying to install Linux into my PC.
I have tried make bootable USB using [rufus](https://rufus.ie/) and also by using ubuntu default Startup Disk creator.
I have Tried all options with `Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS` and `Ubuntu 19.04` that I have downloaded from their [site](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop) 2-3 times.

But every time I am facing the same Problem is that my PC `/var/log` keeps on filling up my PC over and over again or my PC freezes after I put my password.

- Legacy support enabled
- booting in UEFI mode
- I have tried all other options as given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100004/how-can-i-free-space-from-a-massive-39-5gb-var-log-folder).
- Tried deleting logs and still they come up next time.
- tried Erase whole disk and install ubuntu
- I have tried setting up `nouveau.modeset=0` in the boot option.
- Tried Installing with `nomodeset` flag
- Tried `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`
- Tried `sudo service rsyslog stop` and `sudo systemctl disable rsyslog`
- Tried kerner logging disable as shown [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1333674/how-do-i-disable-kernel-logging-into-the-systemd-journal) still dosn't works.

None of the above options helps. I am still getting the logs filled again.
Please help me

`tail syslog` shows the following

```
Jun 26 01:12:25 Notebook kernel: [   36.448930] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:    [ 0] Receiver Error         (First)
Jun 26 01:12:25 Notebook kernel: [   36.448953] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.5
Jun 26 01:12:25 Notebook kernel: [   36.448958] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Jun 26 01:12:25 Notebook kernel: [   36.448960] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:   device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Jun 26 01:12:25 Notebook kernel: [   36.448963] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:    [ 0] Receiver Error         (First)
Jun 26 01:12:25 Notebook kernel: [   36.449021] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.5
Jun 26 01:12:25 Notebook kernel: [   36.449026] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Jun 26 01:12:25 Notebook kernel: [   36.449030] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:   device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Jun 26 01:12:25 Notebook kernel: [   36.449033] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:    [ 0] Receiver Error         (First)
Jun 26 01:12:25 Notebook kernel: [   36.449155] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.5
```

```
whiteknife@Notebook:/var/log$ tail kern.log 
Jun 26 01:31:50 Notebook kernel: [  391.576410] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: can't find device of ID00e5
Jun 26 01:31:50 Notebook kernel: [  391.576416] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.5
Jun 26 01:31:50 Notebook kernel: [  391.576430] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: can't find device of ID00e5
Jun 26 01:31:50 Notebook kernel: [  391.576439] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.5
Jun 26 01:31:50 Notebook kernel: [  391.576450] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: can't find device of ID00e5
Jun 26 01:31:50 Notebook kernel: [  391.576470] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.5
Jun 26 01:31:50 Notebook kernel: [  391.576490] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
Jun 26 01:31:50 Notebook kernel: [  391.576501] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:   device [8086:9d15] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
Jun 26 01:31:50 Notebook kernel: [  391.576510] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5:    [ 0] Receiver Error         (First)
Jun 26 01:31:50 Notebook kernel: [  391.576521] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c.5
```

[system@xyz.jornal file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bl-svP46pqaRXlhxY0McsuJVVjh3WBcA)

[/var/log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UAgT.png)

[/var/log/journal image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpoTN.png)

Comment: Try with `nomodeset`, then install Nvidis drivers.

Comment: I am not even installing anything. It still freezes or logs. I ak just updating and upgrading.

Comment: Please try - hopefully you installed in UEFI mode, otherwise all bets are off - with `nomodeset` it should boot in low graphics but not freeze, **then install Nvidia dtivers**.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia  I just tried this Now most of the space is taken by kern.log and syslog about 10+ Gb and is keep on increasing.

Comment: I give up......

Comment: Also system.journal is creating like 20+ files in 'var/log/journal/2db......1bf/'

Comment: @Nmath as I Told I am trying erase disk and install Ubuntu which means it has erased everyhing and I personally has erased it too by choosing somethigng else in disk partitiion. Yes I am booting in UEFI Mode

Comment: Knowing just a little if syslog contents would be helpful. In future type `tail syslog` so we can see repeated error messages.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix added that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1521173) edit your grub command line with:

```
pci=noaer
```

I'm on mobile but will update from computer with instructions on how to update grub.

Comment: OMG Thans a Lot man. <3

Comment: You're just HIDING the error, not Fixing it...

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub The solution was to prevent freezing for the OP using the kernel version 3 years ago. It may not work for your problem today. You should post a new question and may link this answer into your question stating it didn't stop freezing.