# No enough space

Tags: disk-usage, raspberrypi, user-space

My raspberry get full, I tried delete a lot of packages but even though nothing change ,it still full, I tried also to expand file system ....

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        15G   14G     0 100% /
devtmpfs        805M     0  805M   0% /dev
tmpfs           934M     0  934M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           934M  8.5M  926M   1% /run
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           934M     0  934M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p1  253M   54M  199M  22% /boot
tmpfs           187M     0  187M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: We generally recommend that you copy/paste output into your question instead of using screenshots. It's much easier for everybody. Deleting packages rarely frees up space. You must use `du` to determine what's taking up all your space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the full drive was caused by software upgrade, you can try clearing up the apt cache:

```
sudo apt clean
```

If it is caused by system logs, follow the answer posted in this AskUbuntu question:
https://askubuntu.com/a/100460
Then, identify which service is writing the immense amount of log entries (you will need to fix that so it won't keep happening in the future).

Alternatively, you might want to consider upgrading to a bigger MicroSD card (say, 32GB or 64GB, instead of 16GB)...

Comment: I tried it , nothing change

Comment: Then it's not due to apt cache. Use `du` as suggested by @user535733 to figure out which directory is taking up all the space. Using the `-h` option to convert to prefixes (k,M,G, ...), and sorting the output might help, i.e. `du -h | sort -h`

Comment: when execute du -s it gives : 377104

Comment: Try `du -h | sort -h`

Comment: all the results shown that node red take a lot of space , but i cant delete it , is there a way to delete some nodes not all node red

Comment: Can you post, say, the last 10 or 20 lines of the output from `du -h | sort -h` and put it in the question?

Comment: 4.9M    ./.node-red/node_modules/lodash
5.9M    ./.cache/node-gyp/12.19.0/include/node/openssl
6.9M    ./.cache/node-gyp
6.9M    ./.cache/node-gyp/12.19.0
6.9M    ./.cache/node-gyp/12.19.0/include
6.9M    ./.cache/node-gyp/12.19.0/include/node

Comment: 7.6M    ./.node-red/node_modules/ibm-watson
7.7M    ./pigpio-master
9.6M    ./blynk-library/.git/objects
9.6M    ./blynk-library/.git/objects/pack
9.8M    ./blynk-library/.git
11M     ./.config/chromium/Default/Extensions/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm
11M     ./.config/chromium/Default/Extensions/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm/1.31.2_0
11M     ./.config/chromium/Default/Local Extension Settings
11M     ./.config/chromium/Default/Local Extension Settings/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm
13M     ./blynk-library

Comment: Hmm, that's not it. Looks like it's not your home directory. Can you try `cd /` then `sudo du -h | sort -h`? It will take some time to complete.

Comment: du: cannot access './proc/2238/task/2238/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access './proc/2238/task/2238/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access './proc/2238/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access './proc/2238/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory

Comment: That's not done yet, keep waiting.

Comment: 259M    ./lib/modules
315M    ./usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
340M    ./usr/lib/chromium-browser
348M    ./lib
369M    ./home
369M    ./home/pi
528M    ./usr/share
1.3G    ./usr/lib
1.9G    ./usr
11G     ./var/log
12G     ./var
14G     .

Comment: Ah, I see. So it's due to system logs. I'll edit my answer with the steps to remove that.

Comment: ok , I am waiting .hope to solve :(

Comment: can you please put the command I should use , to be more clear for me

Comment: Do you use the full Raspberry Pi OS or the Lite version? The first one has GUI so you can simply navigate to that folder and start deleting files. For the latter (where there is no GUI): `cd /var/log` then `sudo rm -v *.gz` . Take note of which files show up most: that's the service you need to fix.

Comment: Thanks a lot , You save my life :) :)

Comment: No problem, and welcome to AskUbuntu btw!